# Sails.js: How to access and modify req.params in middleware

Tags: express, sails.js

I want to implement a mechanism to obfuscate the id fields in my application . Right now all the id fields are integers. I want to use some sort of reversible hashing to create random strings corresponding to the id fields. Also, I am trying to accomplish this with minimal changes to the overall project.

One thing that came to my mind was to write a middleware to intercept every request and response object and check for the presence of `id` field. If the request contains `id` field and it is an obfuscated version, decode the string and replace the request parameter with the integer id.

If the response contains the integer id, run the encode function on it to send the obfuscated id to the client.

The problem I am facing is with modifying the `req` object. The `id` field can be present in `req.body` or `req.params` or `res.query`. However, in the middleware, I cannot see the id field when it is present in `req.params`.

I tried using policies. But the problem I am facing there is even after changing the `req.params`, the changes are lost when the control reaches the controller. What would be the recommended way of solving this problem ?

Here is the sample code:

In the policy:

```
module.exports = function (req, res, next) {
  req.params.id = '12345';
  req.query.pageSize = 30;
  req.body = {};

  sails.log.info('req.params', req.params);
  sails.log.info('req.query', req.query);
  sails.log.info('req.body', req.body);
  return next();
};
```

I am just modifying values of req.params, req.query and req.body.

When I try to access these values in the controller, the values of req.query and req.body are the modified values as changed in the policy. However, req.params changes back to what was sent by the client and the changes made in the policy are lost

Comment: some code, pls?

Comment: @SkyQ:  Added some sample code. I am not doing much right now. Just changing the values of req.params, req.query and req.body

Answer (score 0):

<s>I think you are confusing policy and middleware?  Is your code above in api/policies?  If so, you still need to define which controller(s) this policy is applied to in config/policies.</s>

So config/policies.js should look like:

```
modue.exports.policies = {
    // If you really want this policy for every controller and action
    '*': 'policyName.js',

    // If you want it for a specific controller. '*' denotes every action in controller
    specificController: {
        '*': 'policyName.js'
    },

    // If you want it for a specific action on a specific controller
    specificController: {
        'specificAction': 'policyName.js'
    }

};
```

Also I'd like to add.  Policies are generally meant for authorization of controllers but this seems like a decent use case.  Since every single request is not going to have these fields this should be a policy.  Policies are great when applying something to a handful of controllers/actions. Middleware is great when you need to apply to every single action that comes into your app.

http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/policies

http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/middleware

Gitter response:
sgress454 @sgress454 10:45
@mandeepm91

In the policy, if I change req.body or req.query, the changes persist in the next policy or controller. However, changes made to req.params are lost.
This is one of the main use cases for req.options. This object is intended to be used to store request data that can be mutated by one handler before being passed on to the next. The req.params object is meant to provide each handler with a copy of the original request parameters.
How you approach this really depends on what your goal is. If you really need each request handler (that is, policies and controller actions) to see an encoded version of the ID, then a good approach would be to encode the ID in a policy as @S-Stephen suggested, store that value in req.options.id and refer to that in your other request handlers. If, on the other hand, you're really only concerned with the response having the encoded ID, the suggested practice is to use the res.ok() response in your handlers (rather than res.send() or res.json), and adjust the code for that response in api/responses/ok.js to encode the ID before sending. You can also use a custom response if this is only required for certain requests. See custom responses for more info.
Hi @sadlerw, you should be able to modify the code for res.ok() in your api/responses/ok.js file to have it always return JSON if that's what you want for every response. If it's something you only want for certain actions, you could create a custom response instead and use that where appropriate.

Comment: I am not confusing policies and middleware. I tried both. In middleware, I could not figure out how to access req.params since it was undefined. In policies, I was able to access it but modification was lost once the controller action was executed. I made the necessary changes in policies.js to attach the policy to controller action

Comment: I see you got a great explanation on gitter!  I'm going to update my original answer with the gitter response to help people with the same problem in the future.